# Button and text HTML

Tags: html, button

Trying to create a button for an email input. I have made it a few times but cannot make it the correct way here is what i am trying to make.

[image]

I have tried a few ways I can get the button and input fields there but how can I get the button to register the text "Sign Up"

```
<div class="email">
    <p> Join our mailing list!</p>
    <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"> Sign Up
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation!](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) You need to wrap the "Sign Up"-text around a <button>-Tag like so:

```
<button>Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Hey there! As seen in the other answer, a form will also need the submit type on the button. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: You're right, a form will need the submit type. Another option would be a JS-function tied to the onclick-Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line.

```
<button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

And if you are willing to style the **Sign up** Button. you can use the following code

```
<button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
```